# How to store the name of rows and column index in pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `DataFrame` with *named* rows and columns indexes:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

I = pd.Index(["a", "b", "c", "d"], name="rows")
C = pd.Index(["col0", "col1", "col2"], name="cols")
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.rand(4, 3),
                  index=I,
                  columns=C)
```

I have tried to store it in several formats (Excel, CSV) but when re-reading the file, the names are lost (maybe I have missed some options). `Msgpack` works but it is marked as experimental so I would prefer to avoid it for now. I would also prefer to avoid `pickle`. Is there any way (format and option) to store the name of the 2 indexes?

**EDIT:**
I know how to write and read CSV with pandas. The problem is to save the name of the column index and of the row index.

Comment: The first version of the code was wrong (the names where not saved). Sorry for that.

Comment: Accessing and exporting the names of both index and columns is not a problem at all. However, I am thinking about a proper way to import the exported data since this makes sense when using a multi-index, only. But you do not need to use a multi-index to access your data properly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use hdf.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
I = pd.Index(["a", "b", "c", "d"], name="rows")
C = pd.Index(["col0", "col1", "col2"], name="columns")
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.rand(4,3), index=I, columns=C)
print(df)

columns      col0      col1      col2
rows                                 
a        0.098497  0.918954  0.642800
b        0.168266  0.678434  0.455059
c        0.434939  0.244027  0.599400
d        0.877356  0.053085  0.182661

df.to_hdf('test.hdf', 'test')
print(pd.read_hdf('test.hdf'))

columns      col0      col1      col2
rows                                 
a        0.098497  0.918954  0.642800
b        0.168266  0.678434  0.455059
c        0.434939  0.244027  0.599400
d        0.877356  0.053085  0.182661
```

Comment: Seem like the perfect deal!

Answer (score 2):

You can export the DataFrame to a csv-file using [`.to_csv()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) and read it back in using [`.read_csv()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv). I extended the code you already had as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding: utf-8

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

I = pd.Index(["a", "b", "c", "d"], "rows")
C = pd.Index(["col0", "col1", "col2"], "cols")
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.rand(4,3), index=I, columns=C)

# export DataFrame to csv
df.to_csv('out.csv')

# set index_col in order to read first column as indices
df_in = pd.read_csv('out.csv', index_col=0)
```

So the DataFrame `df` looks like this:

```
       col0      col1      col2
a  0.590016  0.834033  0.535310
b  0.421589  0.897302  0.029500
c  0.373580  0.109005  0.239181
d  0.473872  0.075918  0.751628
```

The csv-file `out.csv` looks like this:

```
,col0,col1,col2
a,0.5900160748408918,0.8340332218911729,0.5353103406507513
b,0.42158899389955884,0.8973015040807538,0.029500416731096046
c,0.37357951184145965,0.10900495955642386,0.2391805787788026
d,0.47387186813644167,0.07591794371425187,0.7516279365972057
```

Reading the data back in leads to the DataFrame `df_in` as follows:

```
       col0      col1      col2
a  0.590016  0.834033  0.535310
b  0.421589  0.897302  0.029500
c  0.373580  0.109005  0.239181
d  0.473872  0.075918  0.751628
```

So `df2` is exactly the same as `df` which shows that export and the desired import is working as expected.

*EDIT to export column and index names*:

```
df.to_csv('out.csv', index_label=[df.index.name, df.columns.name])
```

However, this makes re-importing a bit difficult since the columns name is added as a additional column. Normally, this is useful for multi-indexed data, but leads to an additional empty column here.

So I would suggest to export the index name, only:

```
# export DataFrame to csv
df.to_csv('out.csv', index_label=df.index.name)

# set index_col in order to read first column as indices
df_in = pd.read_csv('out.csv', index_col=0)
```

which leads to `df_in` as:

```
          col0      col1      col2
rows                              
a     0.442467  0.959260  0.626502
b     0.639044  0.989795  0.853002
c     0.576137  0.350260  0.532920
d     0.235698  0.095978  0.194151
```

I do not know why you need to export the names of both index and colums. If you simply want to access the row or column names you can get their label like this:

```
column_labels = df.columns.get_values()
>>> array(['col0', 'col1', 'col2'], dtype=object)

index_labels = df.index.get_values()
>>> array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], dtype=object)
```

Comment: My code contained an error (sorry for that): the names where not set correctly. I know how to save in a CSV. The problem is to save the names of the index. In your code, the column index of `df_in` will not be set.

Comment: I have also tried to play `index_label` but without success (as you mentioned, it's hard to re-read). I don't think that CSV files can handle that correctly. I hoped that Excel would work but as far I know it doesn't.

Comment: What do you need the names for?

Comment: Well, I don't need the names but it is sometimes handy to have them (particularly for multi-index or for complex df). It is the primary reason I set them.

Comment: I have read your answer but it is not what I was looking for (I just want to store the names, not accessing the values). @Goyo answer provide a simple answer based on the HDF format.

Answer (score 1):

Does your DataFrame here actually have the index name? On my computer I need to write

```
I = pd.Index(["a", "b", "c", "d"], name="rows")
```

instead of

```
I = pd.Index(["a", "b", "c", "d"], "rows")
```

for the name to be actually assigned. Then using df.to_csv() and pd.read_csv() the index name does get preserved (in the csv the index name is just saved like another column).

If that doesn't work, do you need to be able to open it with programs other than Python? If not, you could use pickle which should leave the object untouched:

```
import pickle

pickle.dump(df, open("File.pickled", "wb"))

df_read = pickle.load(open("File.pickled", "rb"))
```

**EDIT:** If you want the name of the columns index to be preserved with to_csv() as well you could do the following hack:

Save it with (converts the columns index to a row, hence setting its column index name as a row index value)

```
df.T.reset_index().T.to_csv("DataFrame.csv")
```

And then read it with either of these two, first one being (very) slightly faster:

```
df_read = pd.read_csv("DataFrame.csv", index_col=0)
df_read.columns = df_read.loc['cols']
df_read = df_read.drop('cols', axis=0)
```

or

```
df_read = pd.read_csv("DataFrame.csv", index_col=0)
df_read = df_read.T.set_index('cols').T
```

Comment: Oops! Just realized that... Thanks, I will correct the question. However the problem is when you have a name for both the columns and the rows.

Comment: Hum, I would also prefer to avoid `pickle`.

Comment: @MathieuDubois Using pickle would save both the columns and rows name, but if you want to avoid it you could set the columns index as a row before saving into a CSV. I've updated my answer with the corresponding code.

Answer (score 0):

`header=True` (for the column names) and `index=True` (for the index values) in `df.to_csv` should do the trick. Both are `True` by default, say the docs. However, you will have to manually set the index after loading, it is being loaded as a regular column. For this, I have added a name to the index:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# your code:
I = pd.Index(["a", "b", "c", "d"], "rows")
C = pd.Index(["col0", "col1", "col2"], "cols")
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.rand(4, 3),
                  index=I,
                  columns=C)

# name the index
I.name = 'index'

print "original:"
print df
print ""

df.to_csv("~/test.csv", index=True, header=True)

df2 = pd.read_csv("~/test.csv").set_index('index')

print "read from disk:"
print df2
print ""
```

Output:

```
original:
           col0      col1      col2
index                              
a      0.455378  0.830872  0.495953
b      0.707146  0.832009  0.112540
c      0.894997  0.156364  0.521047
d      0.775462  0.482554  0.578177

read from disk:
           col0      col1      col2
index                              
a      0.455378  0.830872  0.495953
b      0.707146  0.832009  0.112540
c      0.894997  0.156364  0.521047
d      0.775462  0.482554  0.578177
```

Comment: My code contained an error (sorry for that): the names where not set correctly. The problem is how to save the name of the rows index and the name of the column index.