# how to preserve columns index name in pandas to_csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, indexing

So it seems like pandas by default silently drops the columns pd.Index name when doing to_csv, see example below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.rand(3, 3),
    index=pd.Index(["a", "b", "c"], name="rows"),
    columns=pd.Index(["d", "e", "f"], name="cols"),
)

print(df)
# cols         d         e         f
# rows                              
# a     0.471456  0.522642  0.428371
# b     0.665475  0.759519  0.996548
# c     0.343233  0.840440  0.510456
df.to_csv("tmp.csv")

pd.read_csv("tmp.csv", index_col=0)
#              d         e         f
# rows                              
# a     0.471456  0.522642  0.428371
# b     0.665475  0.759519  0.996548
# c     0.343233  0.840440  0.510456
```

Is there a proper way to handle the columns pd.Index name or do I have to tinker with the row pd.Index name to agg and split back?

Comment: Is `.to_hdf()` an option? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35047842/how-to-store-the-name-of-rows-and-column-index-in-pandas-dataframe

Comment: I was not able to find this relevant thread. Closing my question as duplicate then

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate question. You explicitly ask for a solution using to_csv(). HDF is not CSV.